# Getting Error syntaxerror: unexpected token > with connect-mongo module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Getting Error  syntaxerror: unexpected token > with connect-mongo module

System Configuration:
node version: v0.10.26 
nodejs version: v4.2.4

[image: Error on ubuntu terminal]

Comment: Use Without brackets.

Comment: This error occurred with in source index.js of connect-mongo module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a newer version of node that supports (more) ES6 functionality (`=>` being ES6's ["fat arrow"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), such as node v4.x or newer.

Comment: My nodejs version is v4.2.4 but still getting same error